# Xcode 4.2 create xcode sample project

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, wxwidgets

I have a task to create xcode4 project. The project will be used by other people to open with xcode4, build it and run. The problem is that we use wxWidgets library and by creating xcode project I have to make sure that it has valid wxWidget library path set.

To get valid wxWidgets lib path using terminal is simple:

```
wx-config --cxxflags
wx-config --libs
```

How to configure xcode to call these commands and use it's output to set library path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). You write text script and it generates XCode project on other developer's machine using this script and puts correct local paths into XCode project or Makefile.

Comment: I found a way to use *.xcconfig to set environment variables. But there is no way to use shell commands to set values. I created external build system and made shell script to update *.xcconfig file. But shell script is called after loading *.xcconfig file. So what i ended up to is loading empty *.xcconfig file, them my shell script update it. I need to do it other way. At first update configuration file, than load all parametrs from it. Any ideas?

Comment: As for shell scripts, no ideas for now, sorry. It's much easier to use existing working solution such as CMake for bakefile (http://www.bakefile.org) this. What for do you need to invent a wheel, writing CMake script does not take much time and after that you get working XCode project with local paths on each machine.

Comment: If you are using wxWidgets, you can avoid using its local paths by installing it using `make install` and then in XCode project properties using `wx-config --cxxflags` for compiler settings and `wx-config --libs` for the list of libraries and local library paths. In case if you put calls of wx-config script to proper places, your project should be portable. In order to check for wx-config you can probably use pre-build events. If it is not found then build will not be done

Comment: Can you tell me which properties in Xcode should i change? because values wx-config --cxxflags I put in "Other C Flags" in Xcode and wx-config --libs in "Other Linker Flags"

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you can't configure Xcode to run anything so you need to copy and paste the output of these commands into compiler/linker options manually.